# How to get the screen coordinates for the selected text within a textarea

Tags: javascript, dom, textarea

Hey all I am trying my best to figure out how to **get the X/Y of the highlighted word inside a textarea field**.

This is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var X = 0;
var Y = 0;

function selectHTML() {
    try {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var c = document.selection.createRange();
            return c.htmlText;
        }

        X = getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset;
        Y = getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
        w.surroundContents(nNd);

        return nNd.innerHTML;
    } catch (e) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            return document.selection.createRange();
        } else {
            return getSelection();
        }
    }
}

function FindTextInsideField() {
    var str = document.getElementById("FindText").value;
    var supported = false;
    var found = false;

    if (window.find) {
        supported = true;
        found = window.find(str);

        let pos = document.getElementById("FindText").value.indexOf(str);

        if (pos >= 0) {
            document.getElementById("FindText").setRangeText(str, pos, pos + 4, "select");
            document.getElementById("FindText").focus();
        }

        $('#FindText').val("");
    } else {
        if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            var textRange = document.selection.createRange();

            if (textRange.findText) {
                supported = true;

                if (textRange.text.length > 0) {
                    textRange.collapse(true);
                    textRange.move("character", 1);
                }

                found = textRange.findText(str);

                if (found) {
                    textRange.select();
                }
            }
        }

        $('#FindText').val("");
    }

    if (supported) {
        if (!found) {
            alert("The following text was not found:\n" + str);
            $('#FindText').val("");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Your browser does not support this example!");
        $('#FindText').val("");
    }
}

function findXY() {
    var mytext = selectHTML();
    $('#_findXY').val("X = " + X + "  Y = " + Y);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <textarea id = "paragraph_text" name = "paragraph_text" cols = "100" rows = "30" > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam iusto regione at.Mei id clita legendos.His ipsum neglegentur id, elit oblique no eos.Eum at clita eruditi.Vix quem hinc ex, meliore deserunt vix id, ei error ludus impetus ius.At evertitur elaboraret mel, sonet dolorum repudiandae mea at.
An iusto menandri repudiare mel, eu iisque definiebas pri, semper convenire eam ne.In ius percipit consequat.Ut sumo offendit quo.In duo epicuri nostrum eligendi, essent regione sed no.
In exerci doming splendide sit, mel omnes delicatissimi ei, at virtute vulputate efficiantur his.Quo possim civibus eu, hinc soluta ius ex.Ea quem dolor veniam mel.Sea ex paulo labores laboramus, te illud ludus mel.
Quo vidit nostrum postulant no, paulo doctus diceret vim et, sumo nullam reprehendunt in mei.Eu vis amet commune delicatissimi.Falli impedit in sea.Soluta appareat phaedrum ea sea.Sea facete postulant necessitatibus at, sea veri probo no.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -

 </textarea >
 <br/>
 <input type = "text" id = "FindText" value = "percipit" size = "20" / >
 <button onclick = "FindTextInsideField();" > Find! </button>
 <input type = "text" style = "margin-left: 30px;" id = "_findXY" value = "" size = "20" readonly />
 <button onclick = "findXY();" > Get X / Y cords </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Highlighting the word works just fine. You put whatever word it is that you want to search for inside the textarea. However, once you press the **Get X/Y cords** it displays **X = 5 Y = 5** which is incorrect since it should be in the **X = ~250px by Y = ~80px** arena according to the [codePen](https://codepen.io/stealthrt/pen/WNbvgOr) code example.

Anyone know how to solve this or is it even solvable?

[image]

Comment: would you mind accepting my answer or commenting on it if it is insufficient in some way? This was a fun one to investigate and answer. Good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First issue: `startOffset` and `endOffset` don't relate to the position of a selection on the screen. Instead they relate to the character or node position within the `startContainer` or `endContainer` where a selection begins an ends. This allows you to determine the starting and ending character or node index of a selection spanning multiple elements (imagine a selection starting in a bold region of a paragraph and ending outside of it, `startOffset` would be the index of the within just the bold element's text, and `endOffset` would be the index within the `Text` range coming after the bold element).

Good news: there is an experimental function on the `Range` object called `getBoundingClientRect` that does get screen coordinates for a bounding box surrounding the current selection.

The rub: Unfortunately, at least in Google Chrome, `getBoundingClientRect` does not return accurate coordinates when a selection is within a `textarea` or `input`. So unless you can avoid using `textarea`, for example by using a content editable div (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) this solution may not work for you.

Crazy alternative: the `Canvas` object has facilities for measuring the dimensions of text, so if you were really diehard, you could theoretically measure the dimensions of the text contained in the `textarea`, including emulating the word wrapping behavior, in order to calculate independently where the selected text is within the `textarea` (don't forget to account for scroll offset).

---

Here is a snippet that visually demonstrates the state of the selection `Range` object as it changes.

```js
var outline = document.getElementById('selection_outline');
var start_container = document.getElementById('start_container');
var end_container = document.getElementById('end_container');
var start_offset = document.getElementById('start_offset');
var end_offset = document.getElementById('end_offset');

document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function() {
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    if (range) {
      var bounds = range.getBoundingClientRect();
      outline.style.top = `${bounds.top + window.scrollY}px`;
      outline.style.left = `${bounds.left + window.scrollX}px`;
      outline.style.width = `${bounds.width}px`;
      outline.style.height = `${bounds.height}px`;
      
      start_container.value = range.startContainer.tagName || range.startContainer.parentNode.tagName;
      end_container.value = range.endContainer.tagName || range.endContainer.parentNode.tagName;
      
      start_offset.value = range.startOffset;
      end_offset.value = range.endOffset;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#selection_outline {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.flow-wrap-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flow-wrap-row > * {
  white-space: nowrap
}

.flow-wrap-row > li {
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

ul {
 padding-left: 1.5em;
}

input {
 width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is <b>a complex element</b> with lots of selectable text <i>and nested, <b> and double nested</b> elements</i>!!!</p>
<textarea cols="60" rows="5">Here is a text area with some simple content.</textarea>
<div contenteditable="true">Here is a contenteditable div with some simple content.</div>
<ul class="flow-wrap-row">
  <li><label>startContainer: <input id="start_container" type="text" /></label></li>
  <li><label>endContainer: <input id="end_container" type="text" /></label></li>
  <li><label>startOffset: <input id="start_offset" type="text" /></label></li>
  <li><label>endOffset: <input id="end_offset" type="text" /></label></li>
</ul>
<div id="selection_outline"></div>
```